# Which is the explanation of the identity $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}k^2 = 2^{n-2}n(n+1)$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

A friend of mine put me a problem some time ago, and after trying to do it, I finally surrendered. I looked for the answer online so maybe I could guess why is it like it is, but I just can't understand anything about it. Could someone explain, rather using logic, why is the identity as it is?

$$\sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k}k^2 = 2^{n-2}n(n+1)$$

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a counting argument for why this identity holds. Suppose you have a population of $n$ people. Out of this group of people, you want to count the number of ways to create a club that has a president and a treasurer (the president and treasurer could be the same person). The club does not *need* to include all $n$ people.

One way to count the number of ways to create this club is to 
1) Sum over the *size* of the club. 
2) Pick the people to be in the club. 
3) Pick the president.
4) Pick the treasurer.

So if the club has size $k$, then there are ${n \choose k}$ ways to choose the club and then $k$ choices for the president and $k$ choices for the treasurer. Overall, there are 
$$
\sum_{k =0}^n {n \choose k} k^2
$$
such ways.

Conversely, we can 
1) Choose the president first (out of $n$ people).
2) Choose the treasurer.
3) Pick the remaining members of the club.

There are $n$ ways to pick the president. Now for the treasurer, we either pick (a) the president or (b) one of the $n-1$ other people. If we pick the president as the treasurer, then each of the remaining $n-1$ people are either in the club or not; as a result, there would be $2^{n-1}$ ways to pick these members in this case. Now if we chose a different person as the treasurer, then each of the remaining $n-2$ people are either in the club or not; as a result, there would be $2^{n-2}$ ways to pick these members. Thus, overall there are 
$$
n \cdot 1 \cdot 2^{n-1} + n \cdot (n-1) \cdot 2^{n-2} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}
$$
ways to select the club.

Comment: No doubt you could extend this to $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k}k^3 = 2^{n-3}n^2(n+3)$ but I suspect it might get a little tiring for higher powers

Answer (score 25):

We have:  $$(1+x)^n=\sum_0^n \binom nk x^k$$

Differentiate to get:  $$n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_1^n \binom nk kx^{k-1}$$

Multiply by $x$ to get: $$nx(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_1^n \binom nk kx^{k}$$

Differentiate again to get $$n(1+x)^{n-1}+n(n-1)x(1+x)^{n-2}=\sum_1^n \binom nk k^2x^{k-1}$$

Now let $x=1$ to get the desired result. (note that the summand vanishes if $k=0$ so you can start the sum at $k=0$ without changing the right hand).

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another method.
Without using calculus.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk k^2&=
n\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}k\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}(k+1)\\
&=n\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom {n-1}k k+\binom {n-1}k\right]\\
&=n\left[(n-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k\right]\\
&=n\bigg[(n-1)2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}\bigg]\\
&=2^{n-2}\ n(n+1)\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition,

$$\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!},$$ so that

$$\binom nkk=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}==\frac{n(n-1)!}{(k-1)!((n-1)-(k-1))!}=\binom {n-1}{k-1}n.$$

This trick allows you to "absorb" the factor $k$ inside the binomial number.

The trick doesn't work with $k^2$ because the denominator doesn't have a second factor $k$, but it does work with $k^2-k$:

$$\binom nkk(k-1)=\frac{n!}{(k-2)!(n-k)!}==\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)!}{(k-2)!((n-2)-(k-2))!}=\binom {n-2}{k-2}n(n-1).$$

Adding these two results and summing over $k$,

$$S=2^{n-1}n+2^{n-2}n(n-1)=2^{n-2}n(n+1).$$

---

Check with $n=5$.

$$\begin{align}k&\to\color{blue}1\cdot0+\color{blue}5\cdot1+\color{blue}{10}\cdot2+\color{blue}{10}\cdot3+\color{blue}5\cdot4+\color{blue}1\cdot5=2^4\cdot 5=80\\
k^2-k&\to\color{blue}1\cdot0\cdot\bar1+\color{blue}5\cdot1\cdot0+\color{blue}{10}\cdot2\cdot1+\color{blue}{10}\cdot3\cdot2+\color{blue}5\cdot4\cdot3+\color{blue}1\cdot5\cdot4=2^3\cdot 5\cdot4=160\end{align}$$

and summing,

$$k^2\to\color{blue}1\cdot0^2+\color{blue}5\cdot1^2+\color{blue}{10}\cdot2^2+\color{blue}{10}\cdot3^2+\color{blue}5\cdot4^2+\color{blue}1\cdot5^2=2^3\cdot 5\cdot6=240.$$